# Android version code

Tags: android, cordova

I'm getting this error

> ```
> > platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/armv7/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:5:26-37:
> > AAPT: Float types not allowed (at 'versionCode' with value
> > '16130110020').
> ```

How I can enable float type for versionCode?

Comment: You can't, that's what the error is telling you

Comment: Float types not allowed means in version code you can't set float as its not allowed there you have to use Int in version code.

Comment: post your gradle.build file.

Comment: yep post your build.gradle file for the app module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VersionCode not allow float values, it's juste an integer used as an internal version number, versionName that is a string used as the version number shown to users.

Ex: versionCode 12345
    versionName 1.0.9

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I think in manifest file you have give something like '1.1' instead of that use '2' because as it said used **int data type**, not float data types as you mentioned in manifest file.