# Convert string to a float in runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I converted a string to a float value, and I am setting the float value in runtime to realm database. This is what I did

`float appVersion = Float.parseFloat(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);   managedMetadata.setAppVersion(appVersion);`

But then instead of getting the right value which is 1.31 on the database, I was getting 1.3099999...
Please how can I work around this? I am new to android. Thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to convert to float? 1.3099999 *is* correct if you have to have a float. Where does managedMetadata come from?

Comment: In Java, a `float` is represented as a finite sequence of bits (in particular 32). So it can represent a finite amount of numbers. Some numbers that cannot be represented exactly, can be approximated. So it seems like `1.31` is such a number. You can alternatively parse two `int`s separated by the dot character if the constraints of `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` are in that format.

Comment: when I log app version, I get 1.31 in the logcat. So was wondering why it's not displaying that on the database.

Comment: it is buggy to do that: e.g.  with versions like `"1.30"`, which would be converted to float `1.3` (assuming no representation error of floating point numbers)

Comment: @codewithbawo most likely because in the LogCat you may see the printing of `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` (which should be a `String` if I am not mistaken), while parsing to a `float` gives `1.3099999`. As [@HarryCoder suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69955598) you should probably store the `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in the type it is declared (ie `String`), or maybe you can use something else like `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` (which should exist as an `int`, again if I am not mistaken) if you want to save storage space.

Comment: But my comments are basically on what I assume you are using, so please instead let us know where does `BuildConfig` come from and what is `managedMetadata`. Providing a [mre] should also help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert your `app version` to a float? An `app version` do not represent a float value, so you should keep it like this. Read this : https://semver.org/ and [Android version code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488800/android-version-code)